# Decoupling of generalized coordinates in lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

Say you have a lagrangian $L$ for a system of 2 degrees of freedom. The action, S is:

$S[y,z] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(t,y,y',z,z')\,dt \tag{1}$

If $y$ and $z$ are associated with two parts of the system and the parts are distant enough that the interaction between them can be neglected, then the Euler-Lagrange equation wrt $y$ and $y'$ must not contain $z$ and $z'$, and vice versa. (Here prime means differentiation wrt. $t$.) I'd then like to rigorously prove that $L$ can be written as:

$L(t,y,y',z,z') = L_1(t,y,y') + L_2(t,z,z') + \frac{dF(t,y,z)}{dt}\tag{2}$

I cannot directly assume that the partial derivatives $L_y$ and $L_{y'}$ are not functions of $z$ and $z'$. Somehow, the terms in $z$ and $z'$ must cancel out in the Euler-Lagrange equation,

$L_y - \frac{L_{y'}}{dt} = 0$

Comment: If you want to prove it "rigorously", you have to give rigorous meaning to "the interaction between them can be neglected".

Comment: I'll try. I assume in the above formalism, the boundary conditions are $y(t_1)=Y_1$, $y(t_2)=Y_2$, $z(t_1)=Z_1$ and $z(t_2)=Z_2$. Now consider the ordered set $\{y(t_1),y(t_2)\}$ to be one choice for the boundary conditions on the curve $y(t)$ between the limits $t=t_1$  and $t=t_2$. We can imagine an (unordered) set of such boundary condition choices: $A = \{\{y_1(t_1),y_1(t_2)\}\cdots \{y_m(t_1),y_m(t_2)\}\}$. Similarly, for the $z$ curve, we have a set of boundary conditions: $B = \{\{z_1(t_1),z_1(t_2)\}\cdots \{z_n(t_1),z_n(t_2)\}\}$. (continued in next comment)

Comment: If you take an element $\{y_i(t_1),y_i(t_2)\}$ in set A, and compute the extremal using the Euler-Lagrange equation wrt $y$, the value of the extremal $y(t)$ you get should be the same no matter which element $\{z_j(t_1),z_j(t_2)\}$ of set B you choose. You can have a similar statement for the Euler-Lagrange equation wrt $z$.

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1271519/11127